# How to change the vertical align of a <p:outputLabel> inside <p:toolbar>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

As the title suggests, I am trying to change the vertical alignement of `<p:outpuLabel>` inside a `<p:toolbar>`. But nothing works! I've tried to change the primefaces classes, adding a spacer, adding margin-top. nothing works! Someone help please !

My code :

```
<p:toolbar
style="margin-left:-11px;margin-right:-11px;margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:-2px;">

<p:toolbarGroup align="right">
    <p:commandButton value="Export Excel" icon="excel" ajax="false">
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="academicEventsDataTable"
            fileName="#{academicEventsManagedBean.exportedFileName}"
            postProcessor="#{academicEventsManagedBean.excelPostProcessor}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:toolbarGroup>
<p:toolbarGroup align="left">
    <p:fileUpload id="fileupload" mode="advanced"
        widgetVar="excelFileUpload"
        update=":formDataTable:messages,:formDataTable:academicEventsDataTable,uploadProgressLabel"
        showButtons="false" auto="true" label="Import"
        fileUploadListener="#{academicEventsManagedBean.uploadExcelFile}"
        requiredMessage="Invalid file type"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/"
        disabled="#{academicEventsManagedBean.fullControlAcademicEvents}"
        style="float:left;" onstart="startProgress();"
        oncomplete="endProgress();" />
    <p:outputLabel id="uploadProgressLabel" style="color:black;"/>
</p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

Comment: there is a attribute `vertical-align` you may try that .the possible values are `top,bottom,baseline,middle etc`..

Comment: @santanukumar : I have tried it inside primefaces classes `ui-toolbar-group-left`, `ui-outputlabel` and `ui-toolbar`. Nothing done.

Comment: no add vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right; into your style

Comment: @MarvinTheParanoidAndroid : Doesn't work when I add It as inline style of the <p:outputLable> tag.

Comment: add it at the very top of your code! you see where your style is? first line! or else add it to the second toolbar group

Comment: You mean the style of p:toolbar ? doesn't work.

Comment: What is your HTML output of the `p:toolbar` inclusing your `style=""`?

Comment: <div id="formDataTable:j_idt39" class="ui-toolbar ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="margin-left:-11px;margin-right:-11px;margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:-2px;vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">

Answer (score 0):

Add a p:panelGrid inside toolbarGroup with columns >= number of elements:

```
<p:toolbarGroup align="left">
  <p:panelGrid columns="5">
    <p:fileUpload ...  />
    <p:outputLabel id="uploadProgressLabel" style="color:black;"/>
  </p:panelGrid>
</p:toolbarGroup>
```

h:panelGrid works as well.